# Can the path of Search module (/search) be changed without altering the module, to allow use of this path by a custom module?

Tags: 7, routes, search

I am dealing with a custom search that, for years, has been accessible via /search.  New site requirements call for the [Search](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/7) core module.  However, that module has hardcoded /search in [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

I can not find a way to change the path for the core module without changing that module, which I do not want to do.

Notes:

- I have seen [`hook_url_inbound_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7) but I don't think this will work, as I still need /search to work.
- I have disabled the menu item, but that just results in a "Not Authorized" page to non-admin users.

Comment: What do you mean by "maintaining the path"? It wasn't there when I answered and I don't know what you are trying to ask now.

Comment: @Mołot - sorry about that. I realized after posting the question, that it wasn't explicitly clear that I need to continue to use /search for the custom module.

Comment: I edited your title to make it easier to understand. Hope you don't mind. If you do, of course edit again, just please keep it simple. And by the way my answer seems to meet your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like what module sets in it's `hook_menu()`, alter it with your own [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7). Example code:

```
mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Copy search to another place
  $items['look'] = $items['search'];

  // remove all old search settings
  // optional if you will also follow next step
  unset($items['search']);

  // add your menu item below instead of usual hook_menu
  $items['search'] = array(
    // ...
  );
}
```

This will unset /search path, and move all it's settings to /look path.

Worth noting is that if module generates links to /search anyway, it means it has it hardcoded somewhere. Happens. If so, you need `hook_form_alter()` or it's analogue to alter also these links.

Comment: Perfect! I failed to think about using `hook_menu_alter()` to actually add the item, thanks much! And your title edits make the question more clear than what I had.